# RobotFramework and Blazemeter

Tags: performance, browser-automation, robotframework, blazemeter

Has anyone used RobotFramework to write automated browser tests and then used Blazemeters chrome plugin to record those tests and utilize Blazemeters performance test tools?  Is this even possible?

Comment: You want to integrate Blazemeters into RobotFramework?

Comment: I took a brief browsing on Blazemeters' website, it should be possible to use it within RobotFramework.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an interesting link about integrating robot framework tests with JMeter - [Robot framework JMeter library](https://sourceforge.net/p/rf-jmeter-py/wiki/Home/). The generated JMeter JTL files, that this integration produces can be easily used in Blazemeter. Another approach is to try integrating with Taurus performance test tool. It's python based, as well as robot framework. The link to information on how to organize test infrastructure with Taurus and Blazemeter you'll find [in the article how to automate selenium and JMeter testing, using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-automate-jmeter-and-selenium-testing). The resulted code can be used in Blazemeter as well.